# Generate all combinations of strings and their substrings in a set -- python

Tags: python, string, set, combinations

I want to get all combinations of of strings from a set of strings. For Example:

```
permut = set()
permut.add("D")
permut.add("C")

def getAllKombos(stuff):
    returnvalue = set()
    for L in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
            for i in subset:
                x = x + (str(i))
                returnvalue.add(x)
            x = ""
    return returnvalue

print getAllKombos(permut)
```

my output is:

```
set(['C', 'D', 'CD'])
```

but I need

```
set(['C', 'D', 'CD', 'DC'])
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong

Comment: you need to use permutations. Permutations also take order into account.

Comment: check it here https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

permut = set()
permut.add("D")
permut.add("C")

def getAllKombos(stuff):
    returnvalue = set()
    for L in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.permutations(stuff, L):
            for i in subset:
                x = x + (str(i))
                returnvalue.add(x)
            x = ""
    return returnvalue

print getAllKombos(permut)
```

This code now works, all you had to do is switch combination to permutation.